# Adding images dynamically to a layout causes memory out of error

Tags: android

I have some 40 small images and I want to add those to a layout dynamically.But it results memory error in some devices.

Below is my snippet for adding images to a layout when a button is LinearLayout tables =

```
LinearLayout tables=  (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
    undo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



            for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
                try{
                    int imgID = getResources().getIdentifier(data[i], "drawable", "package");
                    image.setImageResource(imgID);

                }catch(Exception e){
                    int imgID = getResources().getIdentifier("nia", "drawable", "package");
                    image.setImageResource(imgID);
                }               
                tables.addView(image); 
            }
        }
    });
```

can anyone suggest me what I need to do in order to avoid the memory error??

Comment: do you display images in listview? Are you displaying 40 images in one screen??

Comment: Please be precise about what you think "small images" are. There are JPG images 20kB in size which, when loaded and scaled, could (temporarily) require 8MB for decompression and scaling. So are they small in file size, or are they small by dimension, and do you ask Android to scale them?

Comment: you a listview or grid view and use lazy loading or universal image loader to load the images.

Comment: I am not sure but you can try findViewById to get hold of ImageView probably rather than creating new instance if ImageView everytime

Comment: @Raghunandan : yeah the images are small in size and dimension too.And as you see in my code, I am adding it to linear layout as per my need.

Comment: @saury: As there are 40+ images, i cant define it statically in .xml file to use findviewById().

Comment: use a listview or grdivew. Use lazy loading or universal image loader. you are creating too many imageview objects 40 of them.

Comment: @Raghunandan :Well,my above code is part of a big project and there is the need of that Linear layout because I have some other task to do with that.

Comment: u can have listview and other views on the same screen. recycle imageview when not  in use.

Comment: @Raghunandan : Ok I will try it :)